# 100% loss when pinging newly created Azure static website

Tags: azure, ip, azure-blob-storage, ping

I've just created a static website in Azure, which is related to blob storage. If I open the cmd console window and try to ping my static website using the command e.g.

```
ping mywebsite.com
```

I receive(I removed the real URL and IP address):

```
Pinging web.blah....store.core.windows.net [ip address] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for IP address:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

If I ping the google.com website I receive the :

```
Pinging google.com [216.58.193.206] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.193.206: bytes=32 time=141ms TTL=47
Reply from 216.58.193.206: bytes=32 time=141ms TTL=47
Reply from 216.58.193.206: bytes=32 time=141ms TTL=47
Reply from 216.58.193.206: bytes=32 time=140ms TTL=47

Ping statistics for 216.58.193.206:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 140ms, Maximum = 141ms, Average = 140ms
```

Can somebody tell me why I'm getting 100% loss and how to fix it to have the same response as in the case of google.com?
Cheers

Comment: They block ICMP requests so the ping requests are just dropped.

Comment: is there any possibility to unblock it on my own?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping is never/not a good way for you to check a service like mentioned in the comment ICMP might be block, and it is a best practice to always block it.

If you are checking on a service you always want to use Port Query tools (like [PortQuery](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310099/description-of-the-portqry-exe-command-line-utility), [TCPing](https://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) or [PsPing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping)).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ3en.png]

Comment: And also you cannot unblock it with most of Azure services